# Chart Range Keeps Getting Smaller Every Time It Update From mysql with C#

Tags: c#, mysql, charts

I am feeding a chart from a mysql database and I need the chart to update every 10 seconds, so I use a timer and set the interval to 10,000.

The problem is that everytime it updates, it keeps getting more and more crowded. Everything keeps scaling down.

[image: This is when it first starts]

[image: this is about 40 seconds later]

Here is the code that feeds the chart:

```
void llenargrafica()
    {

        string query_grafica = "select * from humedad,presion,temperatura,viento;";

        MySqlCommand cmd_query_grafica = new MySqlCommand(query_grafica, conn);
        MySqlDataReader leergrafica;
        try
        {
            conn.Open();

            leergrafica = cmd_query_grafica.ExecuteReader();
            while (leergrafica.Read())
            {
                this.chart1.Series["Humedad"].Points.AddXY(leergrafica.GetString("hum_nombre_sensor"), leergrafica.GetFloat("hum_dato"));
                this.chart1.Series["Temperatura"].Points.AddXY(leergrafica.GetString("temp_nombre_sensor"), leergrafica.GetFloat("temp_dato"));
                this.chart1.Series["Presión"].Points.AddXY(leergrafica.GetString("pre_nombre_sensor"), leergrafica.GetFloat("pre_dato"));
                this.chart1.Series["Viento"].Points.AddXY(leergrafica.GetString("vie_nombre_sensor"), leergrafica.GetFloat("vie_dato"));
            }



        } catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        conn.Close();
        chart1.Update();

    }

    public Reporte_Detallado()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        llenargrafica();
    }
```

and here is the timer code

```
 private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        llenargrafica();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are just continually adding data points to the same space, of course it will get more crowded.  if you just want the current data to be displayed, you need to clear your points first.  you could do this in your `timer1_Tick` block, or in your `llenargrafica` block

you can use
`ChartName.Series[0].Points.Clear()`
to clear all the points at once (start the graph at zero) or you can remove specific data points with
`ChartName.Series[0].Points.RemoveAt(0)`
if you want to show a certain amount of data you can count your points
`ChartName.Series[0].Points.Count;`

Comment: yeah, yesterday i was trying that but it didnt seem to work, it would just that there was no such series. but then i managed to fix it clearing the points on the timer block.